# How to give root permission to dynamic mounting printer port.?

Tags: c, linux

How can i give user permission to dynamically mounting printer port "/dev/usb/lp0" to the normal user in fedora os.

This port will be mounted when i connect the usb printer.As a normal user how do i open this port in read_write mode.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the output from `ls -l /dev/usb/lp0` when the printer is connected?

Comment: You need to [write a rule for udev](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#example-printer).

Comment: Why do you want to bang the printer directly, instead of letting your printing subsystem do it? Check on what e.g. CUPS does, it is a quite complex trip a file does before reaching the printer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, a udev rule should solve this for you:

In your user udev rule directory (e.g. /etc/udev/rules.d) create a file called "10-local.rules" and add the following lines:

```
KERNEL=="lp0", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", MODE="0666"
```

then udev system should change the permissions to give every read and write access to the device.

Comment: This makes the printer next to useless for regular printing via the print queue, though.

Comment: For Ubuntu, number 10 is too low. It should be above 50. Maybe it is better to adapt /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules and everywhere where you see 'lp', then add at the end  ,MODE="0666"
Some updates may overwrite this, so it's better to put in a seperate file 90-my-printer.rules (number above 50!)